# Box::info showing "refreshEx"

Tags: x++, axapta

I have a method that displays a validation result using the syntax

```
Box::info(message,title);
```

However, the first time I run the code it displays the correct title, but the message ***refreshEx***.

Debugging the code the message that is being used is correct, ***Valid Account Number***, but what displays is ***refreshEx***. If I rerun the process the correct message is displayed, this only happens the **first** time.

Just in case it matters the flow is

```
Form - DoValidation method creates Class to call...
Class - public AccountValidation method that calls...
      - private displayValidation method that contains this code
```

Thanks...

Comment: It sounds ridiculous but assign a value to the message variable before the _Box::Info_ call.  
**message = "Test";**
I assume that the word _Test_ will appear both the first and second time.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this error (unfortunately), in an AX 2009 installation, launched from code behind a button in a form:

[image: AX2009 refreshEX message]

```
if(HIEItemOrderSetup.RMAvailable < HIEItemOrderSetup.RMQuantity)
{
    ok = DialogButton::Ok == box::okCancel("@HIE848",DialogButton::Ok,"@HIE849");
}
```

As far as I can tell it only occurs when you have a breakpoint on your form, when you are updating it.  Removing the breakpoint will show the original message or at least this is what I have found.

Answer (score 0):

If the message contains some fields from the database, try to execute a `reread()` or `refresh()` or `refreshEx()` method (depending on the context) to the datasource before showing the value through the info box.

May be the cached data is not refreshed after an update or insert.

EDIT:

If you are specting a return parameter from an Event, don't forget that this is an **async** process. An example on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg843664.aspx

Comment: The validation is being done in managed code (.net). The message is created dynamically based on the value returned from the managed code. The message is created using strFmt("Valid %1 Number", typeDescription) which equals "Valid Account Number"

Comment: It's difficult to say without looking at the full object but if it helps, take a look of why this data generated on managed code is not refreshing when execution returns to X++ code. May be this will be a type parsing problem through X++ vs .NET, some problem moving the data throug layers (client-server), or something like that. Make sure you can debug the full execution and make sure you are not loosing data in some step of the process due to one of those cases.